# How do I find the possible values for a constructor in the Perl core modules?

Tags: perl, code-documentation

For instance, at https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html, it lists SOCK_STREAM and SOCK_DGRAM as two possible values for Type/Socket type, followed by ellipses (which I assume mean there are more possible values).  How do I find these other values (or is this a faulty assumption)?

In the .NET docs, for example, there is usually some kind of Enum, where possible values and their meanings are listed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanelupdatemode?view=netframework-4.7.2

I can't seem to find any such equivalent on the perldoc site, and in general am feeling quite lost.

Answer (score 3):

[IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Socket::INET) simply provides a friendlier interface to the subs in [Socket](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Socket). In turn, the subs in Socket are simple wrappers for the C functions, C macros and unix system calls with the same names.

You can get the system-specific documentation on those from your system's man pages. For documentation on the specific call in question, you can use the following command:

```
man 2 socket
```

On my system,

> The socket has the indicated `type`, which specifies the communication semantics. Currently defined types are:
>
> - `SOCK_STREAM`
>
>   Provides sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-based byte streams.  An out-of-band data transmission mechanism may be supported.
> - `SOCK_DGRAM`
>
>   Supports datagrams (connectionless, unreliable messages of a fixed maximum length).
> - `SOCK_SEQPACKET`
>
>   Provides a sequenced, reliable, two-way connection-based data transmission path for datagrams of fixed maximum length; a consumer is required to read an entire packet with each input system call.
> - `SOCK_RAW`
>
>   Provides raw network protocol access.
> - `SOCK_RDM`
>
>   Provides a reliable datagram layer that does not guarantee ordering.
> - `SOCK_PACKET`
>
>   Obsolete and should not be used in new programs; see packet(7).
>
> Some socket types may not be implemented by all protocol families; for example, `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is not implemented for `AF_INET`.
>
> Since  Linux  2.6.27, the `type` argument serves a second purpose: in addition to specifying a socket type, it may include the bitwise OR of any of the following values, to modify the behavior of `socket()`:
>
> - `SOCK_NONBLOCK`
>
>   Set the `O_NONBLOCK` file status flag on the new open file description.  Using this flag saves extra calls to fcntl(2) to achieve the same result.
> - `SOCK_CLOEXEC`
>
>   Set the close-on-exec (`FD_CLOEXEC`) flag on the new file descriptor.  See the description of the `O_CLOEXEC` flag in open(2) for reasons why this may be useful.

Comment: Are all of the things in the core modules simple wrappers?  Or just this in particular?

Comment: POSIX, yes. Despite the name, the subs within are really just the underlying system's, not necessary a POSIX-compliant version. Otherwise, nothing comes to mind?

Answer (score 1):

In the `IO::Socket::INET` documentation, it isn't necessarily completely obvious, but it does have a See Also section which points to both `Socket` and `IO::Socket`.  It's in the `Socket` documentation where `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_DGRAM` are defined. Note that in the `IO::Socket::INET` documentation, `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_DGRAM` *are not quoted*. That is, they aren't strings. This implies they are constants somewhere, and that somewhere is in [`Socket`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html#SOCK_STREAM%2c-SOCK_DGRAM%2c-SOCK_RAW%2c-...).

Comment: Thank you, but even the Socket doc page only gets up to SOCK_RAW before it trails off into ellipses...

Answer (score 1):

For this particular item, you'll want to look at [Socket](https://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html), which defines the low-level routines and the constants. To quote the docs about constants:

> In each of the following groups, there may be many more constants
>   provided than just the ones given as examples in the section heading.
>   If the heading ends ... then this means there are likely more; the
>   exact constants provided will depend on the OS and headers found at
>   compile-time.

The `Socket.pm` file on my Mac, which I found in `/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Socket.pm` defines the following socket types:

> SOCK_DGRAM SOCK_RAW SOCK_RDM SOCK_SEQPACKET SOCK_STREAM

The rest of the networking constants are there as well. You'll probably want to do some further searching on these names to understand what they're for.

Edit: To mitigate the pain of finding the path to `Socket.pm`, use the debugger:

```
box:~ $ perl -de0

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.53
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

DB::DB(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> use Socket

  DB<2> p $INC{'Socket.pm'}
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.1/lib/perl5/5.28.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Socket.pm
  DB<3> q
box:~ $
```

This will print the path that Perl loaded the `Socket` package from.

Comment: Wow, that seems... painful.  Is the path for each file documented somewhere, or do you just have to do a search for the filename?

Comment: No reason to bring up debugging mode. One could use `perl -le'use Socket; print $INC{"Socket.pm"};`. That said, `perldoc -lm Socket` is the simplest by far!

Comment: Sure, but learning a new way to do something isn't a bad idea.